Adding pinescript tags
I am adding a label on top of a bar in Pine Script. However, the label's position changes with each new candle because the bar index changes. How can I add a label fixed to a specific index?
xlabel= label.new(bar_index[5],high, text = "TEST", color=color.lime, yloc = yloc.abovebar)
label.delete(xlabel[1])

see picture
I tried this, but it didn't work..
xindex= chart.point.from_index(bar_index, high)

see picture

If you don't want to change the position of the label, then don't touch it. You are creating a label and deleting the old one on each new bar. Just create the label and let it be.
label.new(bar_index[5],high, text = "TEST", color=color.lime, yloc = yloc.abovebar)

This will create a label on each bar but the labels will stay there. You may want to add a condition before calling this.

If I do that, the label will not be in its original position when the new candle forms. The label will shift to the right.
